# match the dataFrame column and do imarith operation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

libraries--

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pyraf import iraf
```

I have two DataFrame

```py
flatFile = pd.DataFrame({'file': [' /home/batman/project/flat/flat1.fits', '/home/batman/project/flat/flat10.fits', '/home/batman/project/flat/flat15.fits','/home/batman/project/flat/flat15.fits'],'imagetype': ['flat', 'flat', 'flat','flat'], 'filter': ['b', 'r', 'b','b'], 'int_hjd': ['245955', '245955', '245955','245955']})

masterBias = pd.DataFrame({'int_hjd':['245956','245957'],'masterbias':['/home/batman/project/bias/masterBias/zero0','/home/batman/project/bias/masterBias/zero1']})
```

I want to match `masterBias['int_hjd]` column with `flatFile['int_hjd']` column and do imarith operation that is subtract flat file with masterbias file

I have tried different approach but not getting any success

**Approach1**

```py
for i, j, k in zip(flatFile["int_hjd"], flatFile['file'], flatFile['filter']):
   if i+1 in masterBias['int_hjd'].values:
       mbias_file = masterBias["masterbias"][masterBias["int_hjd"] == i+1].values[0]
       iraf.imarith(operand1=j, op='-', operand2=mbias_file)
```

**Approach2**

```py
for i, j, k in zip(flatFile["int_hjd"], flatFile['file'], flatFile['filter']):
    if (i+1 == masterBias["int_hjd"]).any():
       mbias_file = masterBias["masterbias"][masterBias["int_hjd"] == i+1].values[0]
       iraf.imarith(operand1=j, op='-', operand2=mbias_file)
```

If i do normal print also, then also it does not show and goes to else block

```py
for i in flatFile['int_hjd']:
    # if i+1 in masterBias['int_hjd']:
    if (i+1 == masterBias['int_hjd'].any()):
        print(i)
    else:
        print('Not working')
```

It prints-

```
Not Working
Not Working  
Not Working
Not Working
```

But I have to Print `i` here

Here I'm only checking for +1 in `masterBias['int_hjd']` but in general I have to check for +1 and -1, then +2 and -2..and so on..

Comment: the condition looks stange, try `if (i+1) in masterBias['int_hjd'].values:`

Comment: Sir if I print `i` then it shows `245955` 
If i do `if (i+1) in masterBias['int_hjd']' ` then  it will search `245956` in masterBias right?

Comment: Yeah it's a basic way to check if the item is in the list https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-element-exists-in-list-in-python/

Comment: Is there a reason why you use IRAF (imarith) to subtract two images? Given that IRAF is legacy only, it may be better to use native functions. And, for astronomy image data reduction, there is Astropy https://astropy.org and ccdproc https://ccdproc.readthedocs.io .

Comment: Sir i'm told to use IRAF and yes it is for astronomy image data reduction

Answer (score 1):

Your "if" condition is wrong, it is comparing integer value with boolean, apparently it should look like `if (i+1) in masterBias['int_hjd'].values`

Comment: I was doing a silly mistake..thankyou

Comment: @PritamDas Did you find my answer helpful, or do you need more help?

Comment: sir one more help..everytime I do this operation -
`mbias_file = masterBias["masterbias"][masterBias["int_hjd"] == i+1].values[0]`

I have to first convert `masterbias['int_hjd']` to numeric, otherwise it shows an error.. but if i do ths--
`mbias_file = masterBias["masterbias"][masterBias["int_hjd"] == i].values[0]` 

with converting to numeric then it doesnot work

Comment: It is out of the scope of your original question, and it's hard to say what's going on without reproducible code. I would recommend creating a minimal reproducible example and asking a new question. That link may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: yes sir, i got that